# How to customize python unittest order

Tags: unit-testing, python-unittest

Need a method to run unittest in test case definition order, however there is no available method after searching for a long time.

For instance, there are multiple test regarding sound, two of them are `test_AiSound_stream01` & `test_AiSound_stream02`. Then we find the `AiSound` itself may not work well, so add another test `test_AiSound_feasibility`. The two tests will only run when the third one passes, else they will be skipped(or set to error).

I want the third one to show whether the AiSound feature is currently OK or not. And for the other two, I want to test the playback ability of some specific streams.

Finally I come up with an idea, put it here, just in case for anyone who may need the same answer.
And if there is a better apporach, please do share it.

Comment: The better approach is not relying on the order tests are run in, because that suggests they aren't independent.

Comment: Thanks for the opinion.  I'm aware it's better if we can run all the unit tests in a random order.  But sometimes in a special case, I just need the tests to run in a specific order.

Comment: If you have the actual context, people might be able to come up with a proper fix, rather than solving the XY problem.

Comment: Consider there are ten test cases, then I add one test, and two of the ten only run if the new test can pass.  I think of conditional skip, but I just need to consider the test order.  And my leader think it's bad idea to name tests as `test_01_xxx`, `test_02_xxx`. So I just need a method to customize the test order.

Comment: Forgive me about my poor unittest knowledge, I'm better at `JUnit` test, just new to `unittest`.

Comment: That doesn't actually explain _why_. And the framework doesn't matter because tests should be independent in the others too!

Comment: For instance, there are multiple test regarding sound, two of them are `test_AiSound_stream01` & `test_AiSound_stream02`. Then we find the `AiSound` itself  may not work well, so add another test `test_AiSound_feasibility`. The two tests will only run when the third one passes, else they will be skipped(or set to error).

Comment: Please ignore the test names of these tests, they are just for examples.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the relevant context, but the obvious question would be: why not just let them fail in their own right? Or what's the point of the third test if it just tells you the same thing the other two already did: that it doesn't work?

Comment: I want the third one to show whether the `AiSound` feature is currently OK or not.  And for the other two, I want to test the playback ability of some specific streams.

Answer (score 0):

The below code shows how to run the test cases in definition order:

```
import unittest
import inspect


def cmp(a, b):
    return (a > b) - (a < b)


def get_line_no(method_name_str):
    return inspect.getsourcelines(getattr(OrderTest, method_name_str))[1]


# noinspection PyUnusedLocal
def reorder(self, x, y):
    return cmp(get_line_no(x), get_line_no(y))


unittest.TestLoader.sortTestMethodsUsing = reorder


# noinspection PyMethodMayBeStatic
class OrderTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        print("setUpClass")

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        print("tearDownClass")

    def setUp(self):
        print("setUp")

    def tearDown(self):
        print("tearDown")

    def test_2_test(self):
        print("test_2_test")

    def test_3_test(self):
        print("test_3_test")

    def test_0_test(self):
        print("test_0_test")

    def test_first_test(self):
        print("test_first_test")

    def test_last_test(self):
        print("test_last_test")

    def test_unknown_test(self):
        print("test_unknown_test")
```

```
$ python3 -m pytest -s main.py -vv
=============================================================================================== test session starts =============================================================================================== platform win32 -- Python 3.7.3, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.11.0, pluggy-1.0.0 -- C:\Python37\python3.exe
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: D:\PythonProject\UnitTest
collecting ...
collected 6 items

main.py::OrderTest::test_2_test setUpClass
setUp
test_2_test
tearDown
PASSED
main.py::OrderTest::test_3_test setUp
test_3_test
tearDown
PASSED
main.py::OrderTest::test_0_test setUp
test_0_test
tearDown
PASSED
main.py::OrderTest::test_first_test setUp
test_first_test
tearDown
PASSED
main.py::OrderTest::test_last_test setUp
test_last_test
tearDown
PASSED
main.py::OrderTest::test_unknown_test setUp
test_unknown_test
tearDown
PASSEDtearDownClass
```